# Glitchy map AnnotationView Behavior

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, mapkit, mkmapview

I've created a custom `MKAnnotationView` similar to [this project](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/mapkit/mapkit_annotations/annotating_a_map_with_custom_data) created by Apple. In it, I place an imageView and a label. However, I am noticing very glitchy behavior as I scroll and zoom around on the map. Even right after launching this behavior is displayed. The views can be seen briefly in the upper left-hand corner before they jump around.

Below is a link to a gif of the problem

[The Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8NVy.jpg)

Below is the code for the Custom AnnotationView

**Update**
I switched to using a modified version of the AnnotationView apple uses with the suggestions below but I'm still experiencing the same jumpy behavior [jumpy behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8hpyK.jpg)

[a link to the complete code](https://github.com/TOMZACH/GltichyMap)

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import MapKit
import SDWebImage

class AppleCustomAnnotationView: MKAnnotationView {

    private let boxInset = CGFloat(10)
    private let interItemSpacing = CGFloat(10)
    private let maxContentWidth = CGFloat(90)
    private let contentInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 10, left: 30, bottom: 20, right: 20)

    private lazy var stackView: UIStackView = {
        let stackView = UIStackView(arrangedSubviews: [label, imageView])
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.alignment = .top
        stackView.spacing = interItemSpacing

        return stackView
    }()

    private lazy var label: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel(frame: .zero)
        label.textColor = UIColor.white
        label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        label.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        label.numberOfLines = 2
        label.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .caption1)

        return label
    }()

    private lazy var imageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: nil)
        return imageView
    }()

    private var imageHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint?

    override init(annotation: MKAnnotation?, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        addSubview(stackView)

        // Anchor the top and leading edge of the stack view to let it grow to the content size.
        stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.leadingAnchor, constant: contentInsets.left).isActive = true
        stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: contentInsets.top).isActive = true

        // Limit how much the content is allowed to grow.
        imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualToConstant: maxContentWidth).isActive = true
        label.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.widthAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
        imageView.image = nil
        label.text = nil
    }

    override func prepareForDisplay() {
        super.prepareForDisplay()

        /*
         If using the same annotation view and reuse identifier for multiple annotations, iOS will reuse this view by calling `prepareForReuse()`
         so the view can be put into a known default state, and `prepareForDisplay()` right before the annotation view is displayed. This method is the view's opportunity to update itself to display content for the new annotation.
         */
        if let annotation = annotation as? ImageAnnotation {
            label.text = annotation.title
            let placeHolder = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DSC00042")
            self.imageView.sd_setImage(with: annotation.photoURL, placeholderImage: placeHolder, options: SDWebImageOptions.refreshCached, completed: {(image,error,imageCacheType,storageReference) in
                    if let error = error{
                        print("Uh-Oh an error has occured: \(error.localizedDescription)" )
                    }
                guard let image = image else{
                    return
                }
                if let heightConstraint = self.imageHeightConstraint {
                    self.imageView.removeConstraint(heightConstraint)
                }

                let ratio = image.size.height / image.size.width
                self.imageHeightConstraint = self.imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.imageView.widthAnchor, multiplier: ratio, constant: 0)
                self.imageHeightConstraint?.isActive = true
                })
        }

        // Since the image and text sizes may have changed, require the system do a layout pass to update the size of the subviews.
        setNeedsLayout()
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        // The stack view will not have a size until a `layoutSubviews()` pass is completed. As this view's overall size is the size
        // of the stack view plus a border area, the layout system needs to know that this layout pass has invalidated this view's
        // `intrinsicContentSize`.
        invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()

        // The annotation view's center is at the annotation's coordinate. For this annotation view, offset the center so that the
        // drawn arrow point is the annotation's coordinate.
        let contentSize = intrinsicContentSize
        centerOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: -contentSize.height/2)

        // Now that the view has a new size, the border needs to be redrawn at the new size.
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        var size = stackView.bounds.size
        size.width += contentInsets.left + contentInsets.right
        size.height += contentInsets.top + contentInsets.bottom + 30
        return size
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        super.draw(rect)

        // Used to draw the rounded background box and pointer.
        UIColor.darkGray.setFill()

//        let path2 = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: rect.width/2, y: rect.height - 10, width: 10, height: 10))
//
//        let shapeLayer2 = CAShapeLayer()
//        shapeLayer2.path = path2.cgPath
//        shapeLayer2.fillColor = UIColor.purple.cgColor
//        shapeLayer2.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
//        shapeLayer2.lineWidth = 1
//
//        layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer2)
//        shapeLayer2.position = CGPoint(x: -10, y: 15)

        // Draw the pointed shape.
//        let pointShape = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: rect.width/2, y: rect.height - 10, width: 10, height: 10))
//        pointShape.move(to: CGPoint(x: 14, y: 0))
//        pointShape.addLine(to: CGPoint.zero)
//        pointShape.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.size.width, y: rect.size.height))
//        pointShape.fill()

        // Draw the rounded box.
        let box = CGRect(x: boxInset, y: 0, width: rect.size.width - boxInset, height: rect.size.height - 30)
        let roundedRect = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: box, cornerRadius: 5)
        roundedRect.lineWidth = 2
        roundedRect.fill()


        UIColor.purple.setFill()
        let circleDot = UIBezierPath(ovalIn: CGRect(x: box.midX - 7.5, y: rect.size.height - 15, width: 15, height: 15))
        circleDot.lineWidth = 2
        circleDot.fill()

    }
}
```

**Delegate**

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if annotation is MKUserLocation{
        return nil
    }
    if let annotation = annotation as? ImageAnnotation{


        guard let annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "Apple", for: annotation) as? AppleCustomAnnotationView else{
            fatalError("Unexpected annotation view type")
        }
        annotationView.annotation = annotation
        annotationView.clusteringIdentifier = MKMapViewDefaultClusterAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier
        annotationView.collisionMode = .rectangle
        return annotationView
    }else if let cluster = annotation as? MKClusterAnnotation{

        guard let view = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "ClusterAnnotationView", for: annotation) as? AppleClusterAnnotationView else{
            fatalError("Wrong type for cluster annotationview")
        }

        return view
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is one very unusual thing you do: you `override init` and you are doing your main layout work there.

This makes no sense, since an `MKAnnotationView` can be reused to display different annotations.

You make use of this reuse feature in the delegate.

This way of implementing it is also not shown in the Appl project you are citing.

What you should do in your `MKAnnotationView` is:

```
override var annotation: MKAnnotation? {
    willSet {
        // do what you did in override init(...) {...} before.
        // be aware that Apple sets annotation to nil if it is not used any more.
    }
}
```

in your delegate, after dequeueing only do

```
annotationView.annotation = annotation
```

make sure you don't display anything in case of `view.annotation == nil`.

This makes sure the same layout code is used for the dequeue case and when you create a new `MKAnnotationView`

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, please see the updates above. I tried your suggestions regarding removing adding constraints inside of init but the same glitches continues. To rule out my custom annotationview I switched to a modified version of the class used in apples project along with your delegate suggestions but the jumpiness still persists do you think it could be related to the clustering

Comment: edit: make sure you don't display anything in case of `view.annotation == nil`.

Comment: thank you so much for all of your help I think I fixed it by removing the line `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` from the init function of the annotationView